# Opening and closing a dropdown menu with React Native and package 'react-native-navigation'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to implement a drop-down menu using React Native and the package react-native-navigation. I'm having problems with a custom object <DropDownMenu>, I'm managing to display it with an element from inside the <DropDownMenu> class but I'm having problems hiding it again because I'm not able to reference externally. Here is my code

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import {DropDownMenu,MenuItem} from './DropDownMenu';

export default class DropDownDemo extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const {state} = navigation;
    let paramHeaderRight =
        state.params === undefined || state.params.headerRight === undefined
        ? null : state.params.headerRight;
    return {
      title: 'App Title',
      headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#001C63'},
      headerTitleStyle: {color: 'white'},
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerRight: paramHeaderRight,
    };
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.option1Callback = this.option1Callback.bind(this);
    this.option2Callback = this.option2Callback.bind(this);
    this.dropDown = (
        <DropDownMenu>
          <MenuItem
              text={'option 1'}
              callbackMethod={this.option1Callback}
          />
          <MenuItem
              text={'option 2'}
              callbackMethod={this.option2Callback}
          />
        </DropDownMenu>
    );
    this.props.navigation.setParams({headerRight: this.dropDown});
  }

  option1Callback() {
    this.dropDown.closeDropDownMenu();    // <-- ERROR here
    // option1 callback code here ...
  }
  option2Callback() {
    this.dropDown.closeDropDownMenu();    // <-- ERROR  here
    // option2 callback code here ...
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>[Application goes here]</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

The code is called from App.js using StackNavigator class, like this

```js
import DropDownDemo from './DropDownDemo';
const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  DropDownDemo: {screen: DropDownDemo},
});
```

I wrote the <DropdownMenu> and <MenuItem> classes separately, the DropDownMenu has the functions `openDropDownMenu` and `closeDropDownMenu` and they work from inside the class (so I can get the button to open the menu).

The application looks like this

[image]

I've defined the menu as a variable called `this.dropDown` in the constructor because of how react-native-navigation works it is set as the property `headerRight` in `static navigationOptions`. Since I want to provide callbacks to my dropdown I set the `headerRight` parameter from the constructor with `this.props.navigation.setParams({headerRight: this.dropDown})`.

In `option1Callback()` and `option1Callback()` I want to close the menu again but I get an error here that the function is undefined. So I'm wondering why this is happening, and, maybe there is a better way to solve this problem. Is it possible to get the <MenuItem> objects to close the dropdown directly?

Comment: Hey you can use this inbuilt tool https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html